# how to do ccavenuee payment gateway integration in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ccavenue

I tried ccavenue but I'am getting this error. paypal is working fine.

`undefined method`payment_service_for'`

This is my controller action

`def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)
    @programme = Programme.find(subscription_params[:programme_id])
    rand_number = rand.to_s[2..11]
    @programme.update_attributes(:invoice_id => rand_number)
    session[:programme_id]=@programme.id
    session[:invoice_id]=@programme.invoice_id
    @paypal = PaypalPayment.create(:material_type => 'Programmes',:invoice_id => rand_number,:currency => @programme.currency, :status => 'Processing', :created_at => DateTime.now, :user_id => current_user.specific.id, :email_id => current_user.specific.email, :programme_id => @programme.id,:amount => @programme.price_paisas)
    @paypal.save`

```
`session[:paypal_id]=@paypal.id
logger.info @programme.inspect
if subscription_params[:payment_type] == 'paypal'
  item_details=[]
  if @programme.currency == 'INR'
    price = @programme.price.exchange_to('USD')
  else
    price = @programme.price
  end
  logger.info price.inspect
  item_details << {:name => @programme.title, :quantity => '1', :amount => price.fractional}
  response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(price.fractional,
                                            :items => item_details,
                                            :currency => "USD",
                                            :order_id => @programme.invoice_id,
                                            :return_url => students_success_url,
                                            :cancel_return_url => students_root_url
  )
  logger.info response.inspect
  session[:programme_price]=price
  return redirect_to EXPRESS_GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(response.token)

elsif subscription_params[:payment_type] == 'ccavenue'
      payment_service_for @programme.invoice_id, CCAVENUE_ACCOUNT,
        :amount => @programme.price.fractional,
        :currency => 'INR',
        :service => :ccavenue do |service|   
          service.customer :name => current_user.name,
               :email => current_user.email,
               :phone => current_user.mobile 
          service.redirect :return_url => students_success_url
          submit_tag 'Proceed to payment'
     end
end
```

end
end`

I referred this link:
https://github.com/meshbrain/active_merchant_ccavenue

Answer (score 0):

The `payment_service_for` is the view helper of the **Active Merchant** gem. You should use this method inside views or you should include view helpers inside your controller.

Comment: where i should add this, can you specify the file. and code. in the same controller can i add this?

Comment: See [here](http://activemerchant.rubyforge.org/classes/ActiveMerchant/Billing/Integrations/ActionViewHelper.html). In your controller try: `include ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations::ActionViewHelper'

Comment: It would be better if you use it in your view.

Comment: in view means i should include in this path right? lib/active_merchant/billing/integrations/action_view_helper.rb

Comment: @sree, how to do it correctly see the link in my upper comment.

Comment: `undefined method `ignore_binding?'`